# Add extra HTML to colorbox build to display banner above the image

Tags: colorbox

Posted a few times today - not having much luck with replies - hoping someone can help with this. I need to display a banner ad (PPC) on the colorbox. Exhausting all solutions i can think of here - and i'm new at jQuery - i was wondering whether I could append the HTML to the colorbox it self, so that the space for the banner ad would sit above the image itself and then reload every time a new image was loaded?

My jQuery is the standard colorbox download, I'm thinkign i need to be concentrating in this area

```
// Initialize ColorBox: store common calculations, preload the interface graphics, append the html.
// This preps colorbox for a speedy open when clicked, and lightens the burdon on the browser by only
// having to run once, instead of each time colorbox is opened.
publicMethod.init = function () {
    // Create & Append jQuery Objects
    $window = $(window);
    $box = $div().attr({id: colorbox, 'class': isIE ? prefix + (isIE6 ? 'IE6' : 'IE') : ''});
    $overlay = $div("Overlay", isIE6 ? 'position:absolute' : '').hide();

    $wrap = $div("Wrapper");
    $content = $div("Content").append(
        $loaded = $div("LoadedContent", 'width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden'),
        $loadingOverlay = $div("LoadingOverlay").add($div("LoadingGraphic")),
        $title = $div("Title"),
        $current = $div("Current"),
        $next = $div("Next"),
        $prev = $div("Previous"),
        $slideshow = $div("Slideshow").bind(event_open, slideshow),
        $close = $div("Close")
    );
    $wrap.append( // The 3x3 Grid that makes up ColorBox
        $div().append(
            $div("TopLeft"),
            $topBorder = $div("TopCenter"),
            $div("TopRight")
        ),
        $div(false, 'clear:left').append(
            $leftBorder = $div("MiddleLeft"),
            $content,
            $rightBorder = $div("MiddleRight")
        ),
        $div(false, 'clear:left').append(
            $div("BottomLeft"),
            $bottomBorder = $div("BottomCenter"),
            $div("BottomRight")
        )
    ).children().children().css({'float': 'left'});

    $loadingBay = $div(false, 'position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none');

    $('body').prepend($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));

    $content.children()
    .hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }).addClass('hover');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: 2 Years Ago!!, OMG!! im afraid now, as i need the same jajaja

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply attach your banner after loading content using onComplete colorbox callback:

```
$("#your-element-that-calls-colorbox").colorbox({        
    onComplete:function(){ 
        $("#your-banner").prependTo("#cboxLoadedContent");
        }
});
```

onComplete function will be fired both on load and prev/next actions :)